# Block system in anonymouse chat system

Tags: php

I know this question is little bit weird.

I have a chat website, visitors can send message to my users without a membership. I have a problem with block system. I have a block system, when user blocks a visitor, system bans visitor's ip adress. And visitor can't send a message to this user anymore. But some visitors are changing their ip adresses with proxy or etc. and they are sending message to this user again. This is very annoying for my users.

What do you suggest for block system? Banning ip adress is not enough.

Ps: Visitors doesn't have membership.

Comment: I am not sure why you have tagged #php here? I mean, you seems to be asking for opinion in general. you would still face this problem, if you have created this system with Angular + Firebase + NodeJS :)

Comment: I created it with nodeJS + php :)

Comment: Just to clarify to the downvoters: Tolgay Toklar is looking for a way to block user input without having to implement an authentication layer (register + login). One such example is to add a time delay as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452395/simple-techniques-for-preventing-spamming-of-a-web-chat-application

Comment: @KristofferBohmann, just to clarify why I'm keeping my downvote in place: PHP is not relevant here - it could have been tagged with [Python], [Java], or [Ruby] and it would still be the same question. I'm frankly not sure what tag _would_ fit here which makes me think this is off topic. Further, an open ended question _asking for suggestions_ for a problem that doesn't have a good solution (as the accepted answer agrees) makes it worse. Had the 3k rep, I would have voted to close it as too broad - I'd still agree with that choice too.

Comment: @KristofferBohmann, in the question you linked, nothing specifies that the chat system mentioned isn't authenticated. The issue here isn't spam (excessive amount of messages by a single user) but attempts to *identify* a given person on an *anonymous* system, with the objective of preventing harassment despite the existing blocking by IP feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you seem to be getting down votes is that there is no proper way to do what you want.

Either you allow anonymous messages, or you get a working block system (and even most authenticated messaging systems have a hard time getting a 100% safe blocking mechanism).

To be able to block someone, you need a way to uniquely identifying them. IP addresses are not a good option, since even without using proxies, someone's IP is not fixed over time and it doesn't uniquely identify them. People working in the same company might appear to have the same IP to your application.
Someone sending a message while visiting a friend's house, using their WiFi would come from the same IP as that friend.

Anyway, long story short, if you allow anonymous sending of messages, you'll never be able to adequately block anyone.